# VirtualHosts not working?

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I can't seem to get my virtualhosts working... Think I'm clueless to what I'm doing.

httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# rev.dev
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName revcms.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/manuel/Sites/Rev"
    <Directory "/Users/manuel/Sites/Rev">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database 
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##


255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 rev.dev
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, http://rev.dev acts the same as 127.0.0.1 
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I noticed my commands @ Terminal weren't working so delete .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc and it worked.

Thanks anyways! @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Run `httpd -S` (note the capital `S`) from the command line and debug from there.

For starters, your `/etc/hosts` file says the server name is `rev.dev`, but your virtual host says the server is `revcms.dev`.

Change your virtual host file to say `rev.dev` and restart apache.